# Injecting application controller into all other controllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm hoping to use my application controller for displaying dynamic modal components. It would be convenient if I could inject the application controller into all other controllers, rather than explicitly injecting it in each controller file where it's needed.

```
initialize = (app) ->

   app.inject 'controller', 'appController', 'controller:application'
   app.inject 'component' , 'appController', 'controller:application'

InjectApplicationController =
  name: 'inject-application-controller'
  initialize: initialize

`export {initialize}`
`export default InjectApplicationController`
```

please forgive the coffeescript; this gives me an error, that a controller cannot be injected into other controllers. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Couldn't you inherit from application controller instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use an service to hold the state, but you can just reopen `Ember.Controller` in the initializer:

```
Ember.Controller.reopen({
  appController: Ember.controller.inject('application')
});
```

Comment: Your recco is appreciated and duly noted. This solution worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the right call. Just a note that the injection signature should be `appController: Ember.inject.controller('application')`